# Extjs 5.0.0 does not show labels in 3d pie chart

Tags: extjs, charts, legend, pie-chart, extjs5

I am using extjs 5 charts and want to create 3d pie chart.
I am using the following code to show legend on the right hand side:

```
legend: {
    docked: 'right',
},
```

It works in pie series, but not in pie3d.

Can anyone help me to show the legend in 3d pie properly using the following examples:
http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#pie-3d
http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#pie-basic

As can be seen, even example page does not provide legend for 3d pie chart, so I think there must be something wrong.

Comment: 3D pie charts will support labels and legend in ExtJS 6, as well as have improvements to pie slice rendering.

Comment: @Vitaly Thank you. Is there any official note about this on their website?

Comment: No, but just wait for the SenchaCon, it's not too far away ;)

Answer (score -1):

I created an app with sencha cmd, included "sencha-charts" package in the required fields in app.json [image: app.json looks like this.]

added some static data with the code from the kitchen sink example app. in app->view->main

[image: Main.js looks like this.]

Built the app using Cmd. sencha app watch.

This is what my app looks like (since I have docked the legend on the right:

[image: app running on server]

please post your entire code so i can take a look. Ask if you need some further help with this example.

PS: If you look at the sencha sample app from the kitchen sink, the legend is docked at the bottom of the page and can be seen upon scrolling down.

The 3d pie app is just a sample to show that legend displays fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Please read the question more carefully first, especially this line: It works in pie series, but not in pie3d. I am talking about 3D pie

Comment: I have added some sample code that demonstrates 3dpie.

Answer (score -1):

This is the 3d pie chart code screen shot and the screen shot of the deployed project.

[image: code-3d pie]
[image: deployed 3d pie]

Comment: This is totally not what I am looking for. You are getting it wrong. Look what you have, your legend is generated by extjs but it is supposed to be something like you had in your previous post, e.g Android, iOs.... AND THERE SHOULD BE LABEL TOO. I know how to put code to display legend. I am telling you it is not working as expected, look at your 3d pie chart, does it give you ANY USEFUL INFORMAION??? IS THERE BLACK COLORED PIE IN YOUR CHART???

Comment: Just tried the entire 3d pie project from scratch. There seems to be a problem with pie3d alone. The pie charts and other charts work fine with the legend.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for taking time to do this. We have no way other than waiting for Sencha to implement pie3d lables and legend in the next upgrades.